# Selecting Rows with DateTimeIndex without referring to date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to select rows with a DateTimeIndex without referring to the date as such e.g. selecting row index 2 (the usual Python default manner) rather than "1995-02-02"?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-integer), the positional indexer:

```
df.iloc[2]
```

Basically, it indexes by actual position starting from `0` to `len(df)`, allowing slicing too:

```
df.iloc[2:5]
```

It also works for columns (by position, again):

```
df.iloc[:, 0]  # All rows, first column
df.iloc[0:2, 0:2] # First 2 rows, first 2 columns
```